# What does Hahn-Banach has to do with Geometric Hahn-Banach?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

I understand that each implies the other, but I'm having a hard time visualizing the connection between the two. One is about extending a functional, and the other is about separating two convex sets in a Banach space.

Comment: You separate the two convex sets with a hyperplane determined by a level set of a functional.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I understand that, but I don't see how the *extension* of the functional and the separation with the level set of a function are related.

Comment: Imagine a set $T=\{(x,y)\in V\times\mathbb{R}|y\ge|x|\}$. It is convex. Every hyperplane that doesn't intersect it is a linear functional and every functional that is dominated by the norm is a hyperplane that doesn't intersect (the interior of) $T$. Does this mean anything new to your understanding?

Comment: You would then take a point $x$ and the set $\{(x,y)|y<|x|\}$ and separate this set and $T$.